# Are redheads more sensitive to pain caused by tendinopathies?

Tags: tendinopathy, hair-color

Quite a few studies (1) showed that redheads have an increased or decreased sensitivity to pain depending on the nature of the pain (e.g., increase of four toothaches, and decreased for stinging pain). Are redheads more sensitive to pain caused by tendinopathies?

---

- (1) http://sciencenordic.com/redheads-feel-different-kind-pain